# Android Dialog Window Leaked During Orientation Change

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I show a dialog on a fragment, that is supposed to be dismissed when an async task finishes executing. Everything works great until I change the orientation while the dialog is showing: I get a Window leaked error. I know that that is because the activity is recreated, and the dialog is 'attached' to the old one. I cannot use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` on the manifest because I have different layouts for landscape and portrait, so I dismissed the dialog on the `onPause()` method, and recreated it again when the new activity is created. But now I have a different problem: my async task does not have a reference to the new dialog, so it cannot dismiss it...

I have already tried the same thing with a dialog fragment, but the problem persists.

Is there a way around this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: just use a bundle and use the onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Hi, @user2511882. Can you tell me what are you suggesting me to save on the `onSaveInstanceState` method? I am already using it to save a boolean that says if the dialog is being shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said you can't use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` because you have different layouts for landscape and portrait, but take a look a[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) concerning **Handling the Configuration Change Yourself**:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.landscapeLayout);
        //update your view elements, if any
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.portraitLayout);
        //update your view elements, if any
    }
}
```

That way you can mantain your different layouts, and keep the reference to your dialog

Comment: Hi, @Thyen.

I updated the question! The problem is a little messier, because the dialog is created (and dismissed) in a fragment, so I don't know if that solution works (and if it does, I don't know how!...) Is there another way, or can you show me how to do it using Configuration Change?

Thanks!

Comment: Well @FilipeRamos, unfortunately I don't have enough experience using this method to handle layouts. I used the manifest declaration to keep my fragment alive and not loose the reference to the AsyncTask. My wild guess is to use the `setContentView` method in the `onConfigurationTask` method, in the `if` statements shown on the asnwer. I'll edit the answer